# Send Email When List is Created by uploading Rows from Excel File

Tags: list, email, excel, file-upload

I have a query about Sharepoint List in sending emails.

Help needed in creating the below requirements please -

1. Upload excel file contents having multiple rows/columns
   Example-
   Name  City  Country
   Ron   Sydney  Australia
   Jake  New York  USA

The above rows/column will then need to be uploaded on Sharepoint as lists.

2. After uploading the lists onto sharepoint, an email has to be sent to the names given under the column "Name" respectively.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Regards
Chandan

Comment: I think you will have to alter the Name column to a people field and provide either the users e-mail address or the user ID, otherwise there is no way to send the email

Answer (score 0):

Read the excel file as a csv using powershell import-csv.
Add the list items using set-pnplistitem (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-PS) and send the email using parts of this: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mikelee/2017/12/23/test-email-from-sharepoint-using-powershell/